# Why doesn't the function recognize the member when using "this"

Tags: javascript

I have a class called imageResizing. It has a member, `MAX_WIDTH_ORIGINAL_IMG` which is defined as 650:

```
MAX_WIDTH_ORIGINAL_IMG:650,
```

and a function called `setMaxSizeOriginalImg`, and the only thing it does is alert the member  `MAX_WIDTH_ORIGINAL_IMG`:

```
alert(this.MAX_WIDTH_ORIGINAL_IMG);
```

I call the function on load as follows:

```
 addEventSimple(window,'load',imageResizing.setMaxSizeOriginalImg);
```

And the alert box says `undefined`.

However, when I change the alert to `alert(imageResizing.MAX_WIDTH_ORIGINAL_IMG);`, the alert box shows 650.

Here is the whole code of my HTML page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
        if (typeof(addEventSimple)=='undefined') {
                                addEventSimple = function(obj,evt,fn) {
                                    if (obj.addEventListener)
                                        obj.addEventListener(evt,fn,false);
                                    else if (obj.attachEvent)
                                        obj.attachEvent('on'+evt,fn);
                                }
                    }   


         var imageResizing={

                MAX_WIDTH_ORIGINAL_IMG:650,

                setMaxSizeOriginalImg:function()
                {
                    alert(imageResizing.MAX_WIDTH_ORIGINAL_IMG);

                }
            };


            addEventSimple(window,'load',imageResizing.setMaxSizeOriginalImg);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to understand what the difference is between using `this` and the actual classname, when *the function is in the class itself*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `foo.bar()` then `this` is `foo`.

You are passing the *value* of `foo.bar`. This is somewhat akin to:

```
baz = foo.bar;
```

So when it gets called, it is a bit like `baz()`.

Pass a new function instead:

```
addEventSimple(window,'load',function () { imageResizing.setMaxSizeOriginalImg() });
```